# Is there a way of downloading a file (such as PDF) and storing it on the device with Capacitor?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

Is it possible to download and store files (accessing the file system) with Capacitor? I've only been able to find Cordova plugins, but would like to keep the app pure using Ionic and Capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use download() method like this:

```
this.pdfObj.download();
```

Here you can find more info: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/do-you-know-how-to-save-and-open-a-pdf-using-capacitor-and-ionic-4/158634/3

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filesystem plugin for Capacitor to handel file-system and you can write your file inside directory
You can find reference for plugin [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem).

```
downloadFile(options: DownloadFileOptions) => Promise<DownloadFileResult>
```